# How to stop thread in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I need to stop a thread in JMeter when some condition is satisfied. How can I do this?
I suppose there should be some method like `Thread.Stop()` or something like this but can't find concrete info.

Comment: Can you explain how you did it?

Comment: there is a sampler "Test Action". You can pause or stop thread using it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JMeter thread can be stopped with standard JMeter sampler [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action). There are 3 options: Pause, Stop and Stop Now.

Comment: How exactly would you use this sampler to configure to check whether a certain condition is satisfied? For example, I want to stop all threads if any one of them fails or gives an error. How to configure Test Action Sampler for such condition? This is just one condition, there can be many other conditions which if satisfied the threads need to stop!